# Organisation / Management of files on a web server

Tags: content-management, web

I'm looking for a good word to describe the placement of files in a directory.

For instance, putting all files that are includes within an "includes" directory.

Putting images into an "images" directory.

I'm sure there is a right word for it, its just not coming to me today :-(

Comment: Can you add more context to the question? What are you using this for? What is the problem domain?

-- Frank

Answer (score 0):

I usually call this kind of information **directory structure** or **folder structure**. If you're attempting to offer a guide to best practice, you could prefix these phrases with '**suggested**'...